# Como ler arquivos de texto online?

Tags: delphi, lazarus, object-pascal

Tenho um projeto feito em Delphi e em um determinado momento ele deve efetuar a leitura de um arquivo de texto que está hospedado em um site, no entanto, quero que esta leitura seja feita online através de um `TMemo` sem que haja um download do arquivo a ser lido em questão!

Sei que isso é possível pois já vi, a pergunta é: "Como?"

Imagino que se utilize o componente `TidHTTP`.

Exemplo de como o arquivo está hospedado: "*www.exemplo.com/arquivo*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa usar o `TidHTTP`, você pode usar um componente mais simples, o `TWebBrowser`.

Crie uma variável no Private (`Browser : TWebBrowser;`) e no *Create* do seu formulário você carrega a pagina com o arquivo de texto, segue exemplo de carregamento e criação do WebBrowser em tempo de execução!

```
  Browser := TWebBrowser.Create(Self);
  Browser.Navigate('http://websitetips.com/articles/copy/lorem/ipsum.txt');
```

Observe que criei um WebBrowser (Browser) do tipo `Self`, assim ele não precisa ser visível!

Agora basta carregar o `TMemo` com a informação:

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(Browser.OleObject.Document.Body.InnerText);
```

> Importante: Você não deve chamar o procedimento *OleObject.Document.Body* no mesmo evento onde esta o procedimento Navigate, isso gera violação de acesso, ou seja, você estaria tentando obter uma informação que ainda não foi criada! Pois, existe uma demora, mesmo que pequena entre a navegação e download da pagina, aproveite e expanda sua pesquisa sobre o **WebBrowser**, encontrara um evento chamado *DocumentComplete* que ajudara bastante nos seus futurus projetos com esse componente!

Comment: Obrigado, dá um favorite na minha pergunta!